# i am getting some 0 when i am using md5 hash fuction in datafusion wrangler

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

When i am using the md5 hash fuction like this in wrangler

```
set-column :numbertohash "12345"

hash :numbertohash MD5 true
```

i am getting the output like this its 32 0's are appended at start

expected md5 for 12345 is :: 827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b

i am getting md5 like this :: 00000000000000000000000000000000827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b

[image]

please let me know if any one have idea why i am getting those 0 (zero's) at start.

Comment: MD5 is just a 128bit value. For some reason it's displayed to you as if it were a 256bit value (i.e. with some prefixed 0-s). I don't know anything about the tool you're using, but I don't think this should cause any issues.

Answer (score 1):

If 'encode' option is set to true, the hashed digest is encoded as hex with left-padding zeroes. See documentation [here](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/382140542/Hash+directive).

Answer (score 0):

The 32 zeroes cannot be reversed into string, therefore the zeroes can be ignored. It might be a possible bug, and you can file it in the Public Issue Tracker.